# shiny is crashing when given a long list to Selectize input

Tags: r, shiny, selectize.js

I am using shiny to develop a web app for my work, to be hosted on a single person's computer, where the user can give his/her choice of inputs and in the backend, a query is built based on these inputs to draw data from a database and visualize.

as of now, I have built a date based query which works well. but now as an added capability for the user to drill down more, I need to provide a way to query multiple numeric ids (at most 15) at once where the id list is of approximate length 450,000. instead of providing 15 numeric inputs I am trying to give the ids as a string using selectize input.

[this is the snippet of the code for the selectize input widget](https://i.stack.imgur.com/THGFY.png)

my problem is that R crashes and ask for terminate and restart when I run the app. the app works fine for a smaller vector of ids, say, for a length of 10,000. While its kind of counterproductive to ask the user to give an id range initially, is there a way to overcome this problem? Please guide.

Comment: Please provide a small reproducible example